# как построить график в yii с помощью yii2-highcharts-widget

Tags: php, yii, highcharts

Пытаюсь разобраться с тем, как построить график при помощи расширения  yii2-highcharts-widget, чтобы по оси X шли месяцы, а по оси Y  Вот код из офф. [доки](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-highcharts-widget):

```
echo Highcharts::widget([
   'options' => [
      'title' => ['text' => 'Fruit Consumption'],
      'xAxis' => [
         'categories' => ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
      ],
      'yAxis' => [
         'title' => ['text' => 'Fruit eaten']
      ],
      'series' => [
         ['name' => 'Jane', 'data' => [1, 0, 4]],
         ['name' => 'John', 'data' => [5, 7, 3]]
      ]
   ]
]);
```

пытаюсь его для себя адаптировать. Получаю данные из модели вот так:

```
    return self::find()->select([
                        'address',
                        'idinvite',
                        'cdate_int',
                        'fromwhere'
                    ])
                    ->where(
                            new Expression(
                            "idregion = :id_region "
                            . "AND fromwhere != :not_interested ", 
                            [":id_region" => REGION_ID,
                        ":not_interested" => self::NOT_INTERESTED]))
                    ->orderBy("cdate_int DESC")->indexBy('address');
```

Данный запрос возвращает множество массивов вот такого вида:

```
  array(4) {
    ["address"]=>
    string(30) "examplename"
    ["idinvite"]=>
    string(3) "188"
    ["cdate_int"]=>
    string(10) "1536864790"
    ["fromwhere"]=>
    string(1) "2"
  }
```

Хочу сделать, чтобы по x шли месяцы (отдельно формирую массив с ними), а по y количество записей в столбце `fromwhere` для каждого `idinvite`. В `name` я помещаю `address` из запроса, а в `data` хотел бы помещать сумму записей  столбца `fromwhere`, чтобы видеть сколько в каждом месяце создалось записей для каждого id.
Подскажите. как правильно это реализовать? Массив для графика сейчас формирую вот так:

```
public function getStatData() {

    $invitesData = $this->findInviteWithViews()->asArray()->all();

    $resultData = [];
    foreach ($invitesData as $key => $value) {
        $positions = [];
        foreach ($value as $val) {
            $positions[] = count($value['fromwhere']);
        }
        $resultData[] = [
            'name' => $key,
            'data' => $positions
        ];
    }
    return $resultData;
}
```

Но это делает кучу вот таких массивов

```
  array(2) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(32) "examplename"
    ["data"]=>
    array(4) {
      [0]=>
      int(1)
      [1]=>
      int(1)
      [2]=>
      int(1)
      [3]=>
      int(1)
    }
  }
```

и весь график получается в одну полоску. Как исправить данный код?

UPD: данные содержащиеся в `$resultData`: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Данные в `$invitesData`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `count($value['fromwhere']);` вы этой строкой что пытаетесь посчитать? Вы вроде писали про какую то их сумму, но очевидно не сумма, поэтому и 1 всегда.

Comment: лучше приведите пример данных, которые у вас получаются в `$invitesData` и то что хотите получить в `$resultData`. А то ваше объяснение в вопросе не шибко то понятно.

Comment: @teran добавил скриншоты с примерами данных в переменных

Comment: Обратите внимание, что я спрашивал, данные которые вы хотите получить в `result` а не получаете. Очевидно получаете вы не то, что надо. И не выкладывайте код рисунками. Лучше скопируйте его часть, но вставьте текстом. Или сделайте `json_encode` и результат выложите.

Comment: @teran я хотел бы, чтобы в `result` был массив вот такого вида: 
            [
                'type' => 'column',
                'name' => 'Joe',
                'data' => [4, 3, 3, 9, 0],
            ],
чтобы data содержала в себе цифру, сколько было создано записей с idinvite за этот месяц. Дата хранится в cdate_int

Comment: и при чем тут тогда `fromwhere` про которые вы писали, и которые у вас в коде?

Comment: @teran я опечатался, я поправить уже нельзя:( конечно я имел ввиду количество записей в `fromwhere` для каждого `idinvite`

Comment: давайте я еще раз попрошу в нормально виде привести исходные и желаемые данные, сделайте `json_encode` исходных и вставьте в вопрос. И прикиньте какие там будут результирующие данные. Если вы думаете что можно решить задачу видя фрагмент массив, то вы ошибаетесь, так вам не помогут.